# Sign In page is not showing in K10/Grafana. It just shows welcome to grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I have installed Kasten k10 and using default grafana dashboard. When I try to sign in to import other dashboards by logging as admin - Sign in page just shows "Welcome to Grafana" Not showing any tabs for credentials input.

Can anyone confirm if we can get admin access to k10 Grafana to import dashboards or it is just limited to Kasten k10 visualization?

When i try to login - http://localhost:8080/k10/grafana/login - It just says welcome to Grafana can’t give any credentials. Screenshot is pasted.

[K10/grafana Login page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrzID.png)

Comment: sharing the YAML or way you have setup grafana would be helpful to share or help you out. used HELM chart to install what variables you have passed ? any error in browser debug mode console ?

Comment: I'm using the in-built Kasten K10 grafana dashboard. I have installed kasten-k10 with helm - helm install k10 kasten/k10 --namespace=kasten-io

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /etc/grafana/grafana.ini in "[auth]" section to these default values:

```
[auth]
# Login cookie name
;login_cookie_name = grafana_session

# The maximum lifetime (duration) an authenticated user can be inactive before being required to login at next visit. Default is 7 days (7d). This setting should be expressed as a duration, e.g. 5m (minutes), 6h (hours), 10d (days), 2w (weeks), 1M (month). The lifetime resets at each successful token rotation.
;login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_duration =

# The maximum lifetime (duration) an authenticated user can be logged in since login time before being required to login. Default is 30 days (30d). This setting should be expressed as a duration, e.g. 5m (minutes), 6h (hours), 10d (days), 2w (weeks), 1M (month).
;login_maximum_lifetime_duration =

# How often should auth tokens be rotated for authenticated users when being active. The default is each 10 minutes.
;token_rotation_interval_minutes = 10

# Set to true to disable (hide) the login form, useful if you use OAuth, defaults to false
;disable_login_form = false

# Set to true to disable the sign out link in the side menu. Useful if you use auth.proxy or auth.jwt, defaults to false
;disable_signout_menu = false

# URL to redirect the user to after sign out
;signout_redirect_url =

# Set to true to attempt login with OAuth automatically, skipping the login screen.
# This setting is ignored if multiple OAuth providers are configured.
;oauth_auto_login = false

# OAuth state max age cookie duration in seconds. Defaults to 600 seconds.
;oauth_state_cookie_max_age = 600

# Skip forced assignment of OrgID 1 or 'auto_assign_org_id' for social logins
;oauth_skip_org_role_update_sync = false

# limit of api_key seconds to live before expiration
;api_key_max_seconds_to_live = -1

# Set to true to enable SigV4 authentication option for HTTP-based datasources.
;sigv4_auth_enabled = false

# Set to true to enable verbose logging of SigV4 request signing
;sigv4_verbose_logging = false
```

After editing, restart grafana-server service.